# django channels not initializing connection with angular 4 frontend

Tags: angular, websocket, django-channels

i have my django backend running in a docker environment and i have an angular front-end. I am trying to implement websocket to communicate between frontend and backend. On backend i have added
`ASGI_APPLICATION = 'app.routing.application'` in my base settings. I have a routing file in my project's base directory which looks like following.

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import document.routing


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket' : AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            document.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

and then in my document app i have another routing.py file which looks like following.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/document/convertprogress/$', consumers.ConvertConsumer)
]
```

In this document app i also have a consumers.py which looks like following.

from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

```
class ConvertConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
        }))
```

On angular side i am trying to connect to websocket using following function.

```
initwebSocket() {
    let chatSocket = new WebSocket(
      'ws://' + window.location.host +
      '/ws/document/convertprogress/');


    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log("event is");
      console.log(e);
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
      console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
  }
```

this function is being called when another function has returned its response, but i am getting following error.

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://paksign:4200/ws/document/convertprogress/' failed: Connection
>   closed before receiving a handshake response.
>
> Chat socket closed unexpectedly

i have tried solutions i found after googling this problem but no luck. any help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Add print statements to connect and disconnect and check if it gets there before disconnecting